# WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:2181 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I have problem starting producer in kafka on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro.
Zookeper and kafka servers started ok. I also don't have problem creating, listing and deleting topics.

Here is error:

> WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker
> localhost:2181 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

kafka version: 2.13-2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure zookeeper runs on port 2181 and kafka on ports 9092. Check your config files `zookeeper.properties` and `server.properties` for that.

And also make sure that when you are running commands you enter proper ports for zookeeper and kafka accordingly eg. for kafka server it should be `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

After that use 2 backslash in configuration files:

In **C:\kafka\config\zookeeper.properties**:

```
dataDir=c:\\kafka\\zookeeper
```

and in **C:\kafka\config\server.properties**:

```
log.dirs=c:\\kafka\\kafka-logs
```

After that everything everything worked ok.

Comment: This isn't the solution to your error. 1) You should really use WSL2 to run Kafka in windows. 2) your error says you have given the Zookeeper address as a Kafka broker

Comment: I've successfully installed it on Windows without WSL2. Address is localhost, ports are different as they should be. Checked that several times. Things worked only after changing this.

Comment: Installation may work, but as log segments get rolled after 1Gb of topic data, you may start experiencing filesystem permissions errors that have been reported multiple times in Kafka JIRA for Windows users. Regarding ports, `Bootstrap broker localhost:2181` is incorrect as it should be `localhost:9092` as this is Kafka, not Zookeeper

Comment: Added note about port. But as I said - I've changed that, rebooted and still got same error. Things started to work after  folder path change. Thanks for the note on 1Gb. I'm streaming data to Spark Streaming so I'll limit kafka topic size if I see these errors showing up.

Comment: Right... you'll get the same error as long as you give `--bootstrap-server localhost:2181` instead of `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092` to any of the CLI commands